# Go to each white space in a string. C#

Tags: c#, string

Is it possible to pass over a string, finding the white spaces?

For example a data set of:

```
string myString = "aa bbb cccc dd";
```

How could I loop through and detect each white space, and manipulate that space?

I need to do this in the most effecient way possible.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
I need to manipulate the space by increasing the white space from an integer value. So for instance increase the space to have 3 white spaces instead of one. I'd like to make it go through each white space in one loop, any method of doing this already in .NET? By white space I mean a ' '.

Comment: "Detect" and "Manipulate" how?

Comment: Can you qualify the 'most efficient way possible'?  What is your problem domain?

Comment: You can find the index of each space by using String.IndexOf(" ") and assign it to an array list. Do you want the code for it? But like the previous commentators, manipulate how, exactly?

Comment: Difficult to judge what you want to do but you can split the string on a space (using string.split) and then use the results as you wish. What do you actually want to do with the space?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "detect" whitespace?  Do you want an index to the beginning of each whitespace?  Also, what is your definition of whitespace (spaces, tabs, CR, LF)?

Comment: I need to manipulate the space by increasing the white space from an integer value. So for instance increase the space to have 3 white spaces instead of one. I'd like to make it go through each white space in one loop, any method of doing this already in .NET? By white space I mean a ' '.

Comment: `yourString.Replace(" ", "whatever you want")`?

Comment: @rx432: I'm going to update your OP with your most recent comment, to clarify the question for the readers.

Comment: Updated my solution to reflect your need for multiple spaces, you can use the C# string constructor to dynamically create a string of a given number of spaces, i.e.:  new String(' ', 5) is "     "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to replace all whitespace in one swoop, you can do:

```
// changes all strings to dashes
myString.Replace(' ', '-');
```

If you want to go case by case (that is, not just a mass replace), you can loop through `IndexOf()`:

```
int pos = myString.IndexOf(' ');

while (pos >= 0)
{
    // do whatever you want with myString @ pos

    // find next
    pos = myString.IndexOf(' ', pos + 1);
}
```

**UPDATE**

As per your update, you could replace single spaces with the number of spaces specified by a variable (such as *numSpaces*) as follows:

```
myString.Replace(" ", new String(' ', numSpaces));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Regex.Replace` method. This will replace any group of white space character with a dash:

```
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, "(\s+)", m => "-");
```

#### Update:

This will find groups of space characters and replace with the tripple amount of spaces:

```
myString = Regex.Replace(
  myString,
  "( +)",
  m => new String(' ', m.Groups[1].Value.Length * 3)
);
```

However, that's a bit too simple to make use of regular expressions. You can do the same with a regular replace:

```
myString = myString.Replace(" ", "   ");
```

This will replace each space intead of replace groups of spaces, but the regular replace is much simpler than `Regex.Replace`, so it should still be at least as fast, and the code is simpler.

Comment: The advantage this solution has over String.Replace is that the regex matches **groups** of spaces (and other whitespace characters) - so three spaces in a row will be collapsed to a single '-', rather than '---' as String.Replace would do.

Comment: +1 because I love `Regex.Replace`, but it's not the simplest solution (especially considering the question). I mean, you have regex patterns and a lambda expression.

Comment: The lambda isn't needed for such a simple case.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're tring to do:

```
for(int k = 0; k < myString.Length; k++)
{
   if(myString[k].IsWhiteSpace())
   {
       // do something with it
   }
}
```

The above is a single pass through the string, so it's O(n). You can't really get more efficient that that.

However, if you want to manipulate the original string your best bet is to Use a StringBuilder to process the changes:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(myString);
for(int k = 0; k < myString.Length; k++)
{
   if(myString[k].IsWhiteSpace())
   {
       // do something with sb
   }
}
```

Finally, don't forget about Regular Expressions. It may not always be the most efficient method in terms of code run-time complexity but as far as efficiency of coding it may be a good trade-off.

For instance, here's a way to match all white spaces:

```
var rex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[^\\s](\\s+)[^\\s]");
var m = rex.Match(myString);
while(m.Success)
{
    // process the match here..

    m.NextMatch();
}
```

And here's a way to replace all white spaces with an arbitrary string:

```
var rex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\\s+");
String replacement = "[white_space]";
// replaces all occurrences of white space with the string [white_space]
String result = rex.Replace(myString, replacement);
```

Comment: Using your second block of code would I be able to pad the string at the white space, taking the ammount I want it padding from an integer value?

Comment: Of course you could, make sure to properly adjust the offsets if you manipulate the contents of StringBuilder object. For instance if you remove characters, or add characters at the index where white spaces were, make sure to account for that when processing the next white space..

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to replace all spaces with some other character:

```
myString = myString.Replace(' ', 'x');
```

If you need the possibility of doing something different to each:

```
foreach(char c in myString)
{
    if (c == ' ')
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Per your comment clarifying your question:

To change each space to three spaces, you can do this:

```
myString = myString.Replace(" ", "   ");
```

However note that this doesn't take into account instances where your input string already has two or more spaces. If that is a possibility you will want to use a regex.

Comment: +1. This is probably the only answer that answers the question's edit.   You can use `Char.IsWhiteSpace` in the if statement to match all whitespace, then 'do something' would append characters to a `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 2):

LINQ query below returns a set of anonymous type items with two properties - "sybmol" represents a white space character, and "index" - index in the input sequence. After that you have all whitespace characters and a position in the input sequence, now you can do what you want with this.

```
string myString = "aa bbb cccc dd";
var res = myString.Select((c, i) => new { symbol = c, index = i })
                  .Where(c => Char.IsWhiteSpace(c.symbol));
```

EDIT: For educational purposes below is implementation you are looking for, but obviously in real system use built in string constructor and `String.Replace()` as shown in other answers

```
string myString = "aa bbb cccc dd";
var result = this.GetCharacters(myString, 5);
string output = new string(result.ToArray());


public IEnumerable<char> GetCharacters(string input, int coeff)
{
    foreach (char c in input)
    {
        if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
        {
            int counter = coeff;
            while (counter-- > 0)
            {
                yield return c;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            yield return c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the LINQ one!

Answer (score 2):

Use `string.Replace()`.

```
string newString = myString.Replace(" ", "   ");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = new StringBuilder();

foreach(Char c in myString)
{
   if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
   {
       // you can do what you wish here. strings are immutable, so you can only make a copy with the results you want... hence the "result" var.

      result.Append('_'); // for example, replace space with _
   }
   else result.Append(c);

}

myString = result.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the white space with, e.g. '_', you can using [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx).

Example:

```
string myString = "aa bbb cccc dd";
string newString = myString.Replace(" ", "_"); // gives aa_bbb_cccc_dd
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to `left/right justify` your string

```
int N=10;
string newstring = String.Join(
        "",
        myString.Split(' ').Select(s=>s.PadRight(N-s.Length)));
```